# python 3.x Nameerror when calling new class instance because its not getting class variable

Tags: python-3.x, class, variables, methods

pretty much the title.

```
class Generation:
  which3cards = #irrelevent
  def generation(self):
     thing = (which3cards[0])
class Swag:
  gen = Generation().generation()
```

and then it says which3cards is not defined. i tried doing Generation.which3cards before the gen =, same error I tried makeing Generation a superclass to class Swag, nothing. I tried not instancing Generation class.

Comment: `self.which3cards[0]`

Comment: idk if I should be happy or angry that the solution was that simple, considering how long I spent searching the internet for the answer. 
Thanks for saving me from another hour.